# Function that extracts words from text ( array of chars ) and put them in 2 dimensions array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning C and have some struggles.I have to make a program  , which becomes a text (max 80 chars) and put the words from text in a char words[80][80] (every word must be only single time in this array! it is also defined as global) and count of times every word comes in the text in a int count[] (Index must be same as this from words[][]).
The function is called int extract_and_count(char *source,int *count).
I wrote some code ,but I'm not sure how exactly to implement this function.Can someone help me?
I'm also new to stackoverflow so if I have made any mistake, sorry.

Thats some of the code but its not to the end:

```
 int extract_and_count(char *source,int *count){
  char token[80][80];
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  p = strtok(source, " ");
  while( p != NULL ){
    strcpy(token[i],p);
    printf("%s\n",*(token+i));
    i++;
    p = strtok(NULL , " ");
  }
  char word;
  int value = 0, j;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 80 ; i++){
    word = token[i];
    for(j = 0 ; j < 80 ; j++){
      if(strcmp(word,token[i])==0){
    value++;
      }
    }

  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post here your code

Comment: I put some code in the question , but it isn't good and doesn't work at all.It's just a start version.I made a new array to store all the words and then I want to count the value of the word in the token[][] and store them in words[][] and the value in count[].

Comment: I still do not understand your objective. In addition, I do not understand what input parameters of `extract_and_count` mean, what the word separator is, and how you want to order the words in the array

Comment: extract_and_count becomes char *source which is an array with the text (max 80 chars). I have to take the words from the text with separator " " , put them (only one time ) in words[80][80] and in int count[] I have to store the times every word comes in the text.
Example :
text : "c language is difficult.c is also fun"
words[][] = {
"c","language","is","difficult","also","fun"};
count[] = {2,1,2,1,1,1}
words[0] = c;
count[0] = 2

Comment: There are numerous questions of this type on SO which you can find by searching `[c]count words` in the "Search Q&A" box. Perhaps some of these can give you ideas.

Comment: If you pass a 80-char input each time, you have to keep count of the current position inside the array and change it between the calls. I think you still do not completely understood the assignment. Please read it until it is clear in your mind.

Comment: @GMichael this 80-char input is my text . I call extract_and_count only one time with the char text[80] and int count[80] arguments.

Comment: You want use `j` instead of `i` here: `if(strcmp(word,token[i])==0){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if a word has been found already. If so, just increment the global counter. Otherwise, copy the new word to the global array of strings.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Global variables to hold the results
char word[80][81];
int  count[80] = { 0 };

int extract_and_count(char *source,int *strings_cnt){
  char token[80][81];
  char *p;
  int i = 0;

  // Find all words in the input string
  p = strtok(source, " ");
  while( p != NULL ){
    strcpy(token[i],p);
    // printf("%s\n",*(token+i));
    i++;
    p = strtok(NULL , " ");
  }

  // Find unique words and count the number a word is repeated
  *strings_cnt = 0;
  int j,k;

  // Iterator over all words found in the input string
  for(j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){

    // Check if the word is already detected once
    int found = 0;
    for(k = 0 ; k < *strings_cnt ; k++){
      if (strcmp(word[k], token[j]) == 0)
      {
        // The word already exists - increment count
        found = 1;
        count[k]++;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
      // New word - copy it and set count to 1
      strcpy(word[*strings_cnt], token[j]);
      count[*strings_cnt] = 1;
      (*strings_cnt)++;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  char s[] = "c language is difficult c is also fun";
  int c, i;

  printf("Searching: %s\n", s);

  extract_and_count(s, &c);

  printf("Found %d different words\n", c);
  for (i=0; i<c; i++)
  {
    printf("%d times: %s\n", count[i], word[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Searching: c language is difficult c is also fun
Found 6 different words
2 times: c
1 times: language
2 times: is
1 times: difficult
1 times: also
1 times: fun
```

**Above I tried to follow your codes style but I like to add these comments:**

1) You don't really need the `token` array. The first loop can be changed so that it updates the final result directly.

2) Don't use global variable

3) The code can't handle normal separators like , . : and so on

4) You should put the word and the count into a struct.

Taken comment 1,2 and 4 in to consideration, the code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Global variables to hold the results
struct WordStat
{
  char word[81];
  int count;
};


int extract_and_count(char *source,int *strings_cnt, struct WordStat* ws, int max){
  char *p;
  int i = 0;
  int k;
  *strings_cnt = 0;

  // Find all words in the input string
  p = strtok(source, " ");
  while( p != NULL ){
    // Check if the word is already detected once
    int found = 0;
    for(k = 0 ; k < *strings_cnt ; k++){
      if (strcmp(ws[k].word, p) == 0)
      {
        // The word already exists - increment count
        found = 1;
        ws[k].count++;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
      // New word - copy it and set count to 1
      strcpy(ws[*strings_cnt].word, p);
      ws[*strings_cnt].count = 1;
      (*strings_cnt)++;
    }

    i++;
    p = strtok(NULL , " ");
  }

  return 1;
}

#define MAX_WORDS 80

int main(void)
{
  struct WordStat ws[MAX_WORDS];
  char s[] = "c language is difficult c is also fun";
  int c, i;

  printf("Searching: %s\n", s);

  extract_and_count(s, &c, ws, MAX_WORDS);

  printf("Found %d different words\n", c);
  for (i=0; i<c; i++)
  {
    printf("%d times: %s\n", ws[i].count, ws[i].word);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That is exactly what I wanted .

Comment: I would like the code to be like the prototype int extract_and_count(char *source,int *count)
in which source is char [] , and count is int array for the repeats of any word

Answer (score 0):

```
 while( p != NULL ){
    strcpy(token[i],p);
    printf("%s\n",*(token+i));
    i++;
    p = strtok(NULL , " ");   --> here you are just splitting the words
  }
```

Now token will contain all the words in splitted manner, not as per your requirement of "each word only once". You can compare and copy the unique words to another array and in the same loop, you can count and update the count array.

Note: You should not use one counter variable on the whole, the array of counter only shall be used to count the words.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX 80
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH  79
#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x) //number literal convert to string

char words[NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX][MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];
int Words_entry = 0;

static inline int hash(const char *str){
    return (tolower(*str) - 'a')*3;//3:(NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX / 26), 26 : a-z
}

char *extract(char **sp){//extract word
    char *p = *sp;
    while(*p && !isalpha(*p))//skip not alpha
        ++p;
    if(!*p)
        return NULL;
    char *ret = p;//first word
    while(*p && isalpha(*p))//skip alpha
        ++p;//*p = tolower(*p);
    if(!*p){
        *sp = p;
    } else {
        *p = '\0';
        *sp = ++p;//rest
    }

    return ret;
}

int extract_and_count(char *source, int *count){
    char *sp = source;
    char *word;
    int word_count = 0;

    while(word = extract(&sp)){
        if(Words_entry == NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX){
            fprintf(stderr, "words table is full.\n");
            return word_count;
        }

        int index = hash(word);
        while(1){
            if(*words[index]){
                if(strcasecmp(words[index], word) == 0){//ignore case
                    ++count[index];
                    break;
                }
                if(++index == NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX){
                    index = 0;
                }
            } else {
                strcpy(words[index], word);
                count[index] = 1;
                ++Words_entry;
                break;
            }
        }
        ++word_count;
    }
    return word_count;
}

int main(void){
    int count[NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX] = {0};
    char text[MAX_WORD_LENGTH+1];

    while(1==scanf("%" S(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "[^\n]%*c", text)){//end if only enter press.
        extract_and_count(text, count);
    }
    //print result
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_WORDS_MAX; ++i){
        if(*words[i]){
            printf("%s : %d\n", words[i], count[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```